# Blowup of six points in $\mathbb{P}^2$

Tags: algebraic-geometry, projective-space, blowup

I have been looking at sequential blowups of six points $P_i$ in $\mathbb{P}^2$. In the general case, we can identify the blowup with a nonsingular cubic surface in $\mathbb{P}^3$ and under this identification the 27 lines on this surface are

- 6 $E_i$, the exceptional line of $P_i$.
- 15 $F_{ij}$, the strict transform of the line through $P_i$ and $P_j$.
- 6 $G_i$, the strict transform of the conic passing through all $P_j$ except $P_i$.

The thing I have been interested in, is what happens to the $E_i, F_{ij}$ and $G_i$ when the points $P_i$ are in a nongeneral position, for instance is three of them are collinear. And for lines being contracted to one point, I have counted the number of lines passing through this point.

I have done this when all the points are in $\mathbb{P}^2$. But I do not know how to think about it when say $P_2$ is a point on $E_1$. Does it even make sense to talk about the line through $P_1$ and $P_2$?

Comment: Sure, you can do lots of the same things for "infinitely near" basepoints. For example if $P_2$ is a point on $E_1$, then it corresponds to a tangent direction at $P_1$. The line through $P_1$ and $P_2$ is then the (proper transform of the) line through $P_1$ with the given tangent direction.